# CDC (Change Data Capture) in Google Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-sql

Any way to capture data changes in a Google Cloud SQL database that can trigger external scripts, for real time data replication (e.g. Cloud SQL instance that replicates changes to a MySQL instance in an office, and viceversa).

A poll solution would work but it wouldn't be "real time" ... if I poll the Cloud SQL instance say every 10 seconds, I would have a max latency of 9 seconds and a huge Cloud SQL invoice for 8,640 reads per day ;).

Thanks!

M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can now create read-only replicas of your Google Cloud SQL instances in other hosting environments, [see these docs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/replication).